# How to use grep match string then look for other string

Tags: regex, perl, shell, grep

Is it possible to look for 'string1' if its true then look for 'string2' using grep.
Here is my situation. i have many txt report files in that i need to search for 'FAIL' based on test path 'Test path: path/to/test'
sample report file:

```
     Test path:          path/to_tests/t1 
     Host name:                   testpc1
                  AMEND_1/Sec3/E30012.c,          ;               PASS;     ;              ;             ;          ;
                  AMEND_1/Sec3/E30013.c,          ;               FAIL;     ;              ;             ;          ;
                  AMEND_1/Sec3/E30014.c,          ;               PASS;     ;              ;             ;          ;
                  AMEND_1/Sec3/E30015.c,          ;               FAIL;     ;              ;             ;          ;
```

I'm trying following command, but it prints only FAIL lines but not test path, also i want to remove ';' in the lines.

```
 find . -name "*concat.txt" | xargs grep -E 'Test path: path/to_tests/t1' grep -e 'FAIL'
```

Please guide me how can i achieve this using one line command.

desire output:

```
 Test path:          path/to_tests/t1   AMEND_1/Sec3/E30013.c  FAIL
 Test path:          path/to_tests/t1   AMEND_1/Sec3/E30015.c  FAIL
```

Comment: Please add your desire output.

Comment: In a one-line command? Why is that important? How important is it?

Comment: we have big shell script that handles report comparison and excel generate.. so wanted to add one line command before it starts comparison. So Wanted to redirect failures to file and send to team, It will be useful for team members to look only for failed tests.

Comment: Ok, but so far, I haven't heard any reason as to why it needs to be a single command...

Comment: I don't want to mess the shell script becz i'm not expert at shell scripts. so planning to have one line command so that i can just place it in shell script before it starts the excel generation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple with Awk.

```
awk '/Test path:/ { t=$0; next }
    $3 == "FAIL;" ( print t, $2, $3 }' **/*concat.txt
```

If your shell is too old to support the `**` wildcard, or you genuinely have matches on this wildcard which are not plain files, you might want to keep your `find` command, and pipe that to Awk.

This will retain the semicolon after `FAIL`. It's easy to get rid of before printing if that's a problem; `sub(";", "", $3):`

The regex on the first line just looks for "Test path:" -- if you want to look for a specific path, you'll need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: thank you triplee, it works perfectly. i will try to insert this line in shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
find . -name "*concat.txt" | (read file && egrep 'Test path:[ \t]*path/to_tests/t1' $file && grep 'FAIL' $file)
```

I'm not sure about the whitespace in the line `Test path; (...)`, so I added the pattern `[ \t]*` to match any whitespace you might encounter there.

This will print:

```
Test path: (whitespace) path/to_tests/t1   
AMEND_1/Sec3/E30013.c,          ;               FAIL;     ;
AMEND_1/Sec3/E30015.c,          ;               FAIL;     ;
```

If you need exactly the output as stated in your question, you will need more than one line, to do it eloquently and probably need to use other commands, like `sed`, `awk` or *perl regexps*.

A version with some `sed` to better format the output.

```
find . -name "*concat.txt" | (read file && egrep 'Test path:[ \t]*path/to_tests/t1' $file | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' && grep 'FAIL' $file | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/[ \t]*;[ \t]*//' | sed 's/,\(FAIL\).*/ \1/')
```

Comment: It's not printing as you showed above, it prints only the `Test path: (whitespace) path/to_tests/t1` and cursor wont come out of execution mode.

Comment: It's very rare to need to pipe `sed` to `sed`. You'll want to refactor that to a single `sed` script, probably also factoring in the `grep`. See http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep